# How to initialize Map in a constructor in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to do something like this (code below) but the IDE flags it. Is there any possible way to do this?
Thanks.

```
final Map userInfo;

UserProfile({this.userInfo = {} });
```

Comment: If you read the message in your IDE, it should say that you need to initialize it using 'const'. So just change it to 'this.userInfo = const {}' and the error should be gone (tho I personally would also define the types that this Map will hold)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: While using `const {}` would work, it might not do what you *want* if you intend for `UserProfile` to modify the `Map`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize List/Map as a default argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418736/how-to-initialize-list-map-as-a-default-argument)

Comment: It's just for display no modification.

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't understand why we need to use const {}. Moreover, I cannot change the value of the Map. For example : when I try to add a new element myMap[id]=newelement, I get the following error : Unhandled exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
class UserProfile {
  final Map userInfo;

  const UserProfile({this.userInfo = const {}});
}
```

Comment: Also note that a constant map is immutable meaning you will not be able to edit the userInfo map, only re-assign it. adding values to the map will throw a runtime error